# Warning you must upgrade to the latest version of google-spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to implement a project when I get some data from a google spreadsheet and insert into a database. Inserting part is not important for me yet. When I am trying to get the data from google spreadsheet document I get this Warning!

```
 WARNING! You must upgrade to the latest version of google-spreadsheet!
 Google's deprecation date for the v3 sheets API is March 3rd 2020
 Bad news - this version of this module will stop working on that date :(
 Good news - the new version of the module uses the newer v4 api :)
 However, there are breaking changes, so please see the docs site
 https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet
```

It's still give me the data, but I get the warning.
Somebody who knows how do i get rid of that warning?

Comment: can you put you code  here ?

Comment: @JeremyThille I have tried to install the lastest version and my program was not working anymore :))). Apparently the vesion google-spreadsheet@2.0.6 doesn't have this warning. So I recommend npm install google-spreadsheet@2.0.6

Comment: @AmitKadivar thx for your time to answer, but i found a way to get rid of that warning. Anyway. There was a lib version warning.

Comment: anyway, Thx for your time and interest to help me guys

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.   We need to see what is giving you this error  Please ensure you are using the proper google sheets api https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

### The Google Sheets API has been upgrade from version v3 to version v4

What does it mean?

- It means that certain method names, parameters and building of the authentication client have changed.
- If you are using an old code based on v3, so building the authentication client as
  `const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v3', auth});`, your code will stop working in the near future
- While Google specifies March 3rd 2020 as the deprecation date, there is still some grace period, but your code could stop working any time!
- So, please update your code by changing to `const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v3', auth});`
- Adapt other parts of the authentication flow if necessary to the new procedure provided in the [quickstart for v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs)
- Go through the [references](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest) to see if any of the requests you are using has changed and adapt as necessary.